# Django primary key field not showing up in postgres database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a model class

```
import uuid
import datetime, pytz

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Topic(models.Model):
    key = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=168)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, pytz.UTC))
    keyword_json = models.TextField()
    model_bin = models.BinaryField()
    article_ttl = models.FloatField(default=48.0)
    timeliness = models.FloatField(defautl=4.0)
```

It results in a migrations file containing the block

```
    name='Topic',
    fields=[
        ('key', models.UUIDField(...)),
        ('name', models.CharField(...)),
        ('created', models.DateTimeField()),
        ('updated', models.DateTimeField(...)),
        ('keywords_json', models.TextField()),
        ('model_bin', models.BinaryField()),
        ('article_ttl', models.FloatField(...)),
        ('timeliness', models.FloatField(...)),
        ('owner', models.ForeignKey(...))     
    ]
```

However the `key` field is not present in the PostgreSQL database.

This results in errors in any code that tries to access the `Topic` model objects from the database.

This code is being run in kubernetes with Postgres hosted as its own service.
I've gone into one of the pods running the service.  This pod has the environment variables that define the host, port, user, database and password;  I've checked the database using `psycopg2` running inside that pod and using those environment variables.  Therefore I am very confident that I am accessing the database in exactly the same way as the django webapp is.

I've gone through the process of `python manage.py flush; python manage.py migrate`.

I've gone through the process of explicitly deleting the tables used by the webapp (again, in python via `psycopg2` running in the pod where the django service itself runs) and then running `python manage.py migrate`.  The tables do get reconstructed (so I'm confident I'm looking at the right database).  However the `key` field is missing from the database.

I don't have the permissions to create a completely new database, so removing the tables is the closest I can get to starting from a clean slate.

```
# having run python manage.py shell on a pod running the django service
 
>>> import os
>>> import psycopg2
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=os.environ['POSTGRES_DB'], user=...rest from os.environ...)
>>> curr = conn.cursor()
>>> curr.execute("""SELECT column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length, column_default, is_nullable FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='channels_topic';""")
>>> res = list(curr)
>>> res

[('name', 'character_varying', 168, None, 'NO'),
('created', 'timestamp with time zone', None, None, 'NO'),
('updated', 'timestamp with time zone', Non, None, 'NO'),
('keyword_json', 'text', None, None, 'NO'),
('model_bin', 'bytea', None, None, 'NO'),
('article_ttl', 'double precision', None, None, 'NO'),
('timeliness', 'double precision', None, None, 'NO'),
('owner_id', 'integer', None, None, 'YES')
]
```

I've also been able to log in to pgadmin and verify in this system that postgres only sees 8 columns (name, created, updated, keyword_json, model_bin, article_ttl, timeliness, owner_id) instead of the the 9 fields in the Topic class.

Comment: 1) Are you sure you are looking at the correct Postgres instance when looking for the field?  2) Did you run the migration? 2) Are you sure you migrated to the correct Postgres instance? 4) In `psql` what does `\d <table_name>` return? **ADD ANSWERS as update to question as text**.

Comment: No its not,  I asked for the output of `\d channels_topic` from `psql`.  While you are there also do `\dt *.channels.topic`  and `show search_path;` and return the results.